# Wierd firefox issue in title jqGrid

Tags: jquery, firefox, jqgrid

I am using old version of jQGrid i.e. v3.6.4.

As it doesnt support tooltip i introduced in this manner

```
afterInsertRow : function(rowId, rowdata, rowElem){
                        $(this).setCell(rowId, 'firstName', '', '',{ title: rowdata.firstName, alt:rowdata.firstName});
                        $(this).setCell(rowId, 'lastName', '', '',{ title: rowdata.lastName, alt:rowdata.lastName});
                        $(this).setCell(rowId, 'problem', '', '',{ title: rowdata.problem, alt:rowdata.problem});
                        $(this).setCell(rowId, 'allergy', '', '',{ title: rowdata.allergy, alt:rowdata.allergy});
                        $(this).setCell(rowId, 'medication', '', '',{ title: rowdata.medication, alt:rowdata.medication});
                    }
```

This way i associate Titles to cells. I am able to see titles in Chrome and IE but FF works mystically in the sense that it only shows the title to once you move in to jqgrid container and no tooltip after that. But you move out and visit again it will show it just once again.

Adding more to it when I use firebug's edit feature. and play around html just editing a single character and undoing it. Its starts working.

I am out of ideas now can someone help.

Comment: Which version of FF you use? What text will be placed in the `title` attribute? What changes exactly you made in firebug? Do you tried whether you have any problems in jqGrid 4.3.1? By the way the usage of `afterInsertRow` make working of the grid much slowly because you can't use `gridview: true` setting.

Comment: @Oleg I am using FF9. Title text is same as the cellValue. in firebug the I just remove a d from div and undo the change. I know 3.6.5 introduced the title at colModel option but i am restricted to use 3.6.4 for now. Where can I read more about the last comment that you made. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A friend of mine figured out whats going wrong here. In grid.base.js source i found that events on mouseleover and mouseout both returns false. Which actually is nothing but a known firefox bug. overridden that function and titles are coming fine in firefox as well.